# Can't access images outside site folder

Tags: html

I have two sites that I would like to be able to share a folder for images, this is the file structure...

```
home/tatty27
      |
      |_____public_html
            |
            |     
            |____upload
            |
            |____new_x-rayqa
            |
            |____x-rayqa
```

I have tried the following paths to try and make it work but nothing works

```
<img src="../../upload/image.jpg">
<img src="/public_html/upload/image.jpg">
<img src="../upload/image.jpg">
```

The folder was originally in the x-rayqa folder (x-rayqa/upload) and I have copied it to the root of the public_html folder so I have also tried accessing it from the new_x-rayqa site by using both

```
<img src="../x-rayqa/upload/image.jpg">
<img src="../../x-rayqa/upload/image.jpg">
```

But I still can't access the images from new_x-rayqa.  What am I missing?

I have checked the path via the properties on the server and it is...

```
/public_html/upload/image.jpg
```

Comment: How are the roots of your site defined?

Comment: I've updated the diagram to demonstrate the entire folder structure

Comment: No I mean in terms of the web server. The config file will specify the root paths of both sites and I'm thinking that they don't have access to uploads.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, that was bit beyond me.  Our web server has security so tight yu wouldn't believe and the hosting company keep changing things too.  I'm in the process of emailing them to ask if they can tell me why it isn't working.  I don't even have access to the config files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that public_html is the document root.
Then this should work:

```
<img src="/upload/image.jpg">
```

Anyway, ask your error log.

Comment: Last idea: Proof directory rights at file system and at web server config.

Answer (score 0):

The relative file path from the root of the directory 'public_html' to the images should be '/upload/image.jpg'. That should do the trick.